Rigid symmetric monoidal category implies closed?
From def. 2.1 in Internal hom it is said that

Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be a tensor category. An internal hom in $\mathcal{C}$ is a functor $$\underline{\text{Hom}}(-,-):\mathcal{C}^{\text{opp}} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$$ such that $\forall X \in \mathcal{C}$, we have a pair of adjoint functors $- \otimes X \dashv \underline{\text{Hom}}(X,-)$. If this exists, then $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ is called a closed monoidal category.

Am I correct in that it follows directly from definitions, that a rigid monoidal category must be closed, since it has all internal hom objects? I am unsure if the other direction holds, but I suspect not, since I am not sure that reflexivity for all $X \in \mathcal{C}$ follows from being closed (unless it is somehow forced by the adjointness, but I think not).
I am using rigid in the sense of Tannakian Categories (see page 9).


Yes, rigid monoidal categories are closed, with the internal hom being given by $[X, Y] = X^{\ast} \otimes Y$. (This should be true even without requiring that $\otimes$ be symmetric but in the non-symmetric case we have to distinguish between left and right duals and then I'm not sure off the top of my head what the right statement is.)

No, closed monoidal categories need not be rigid. For example $\text{Vect}$ is closed monoidal with $[X, Y]$ being the usual vector space of linear maps $X \to Y$, but the dualizable objects are exactly the finite-dimensional vector spaces. Basically the issue is that the closed monoidal structure provides a candidate for the counit map, namely the evaluation map $X \otimes [X, 1] \to 1$, but does not provide a candidate for the unit map.



Regarding 1., is $[X,Y] = X^* \otimes Y$ correct, or do you mean $=$ in the sense of isomorphism?
Hm, perhaps $=$ follows from yoneda embedding? No, I don't think they are equal, actually.

@Ben123: I mean you can take the internal hom functor $[X, Y]$ to be defined by $X^{\ast} \otimes Y$, and this functor will satisfy the necessary universal property. Both of these things are only well-defined up to unique isomorphism anyway.
